# NoMethodError: undefined method `more_results' for #<Mysql>

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

I am trying to create rake task to import data from my old php application.But I can not connect to mysql database properly, when I run Old::User.all on rails console ,I get this error :

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `more_results' for #<Mysql>

        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:623:in `select'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:7:in `select_all'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:56:in `select_all'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:467:in `find_by_sql'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/relation.rb:64:in `to_a'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:143:in `all'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:439:in `__send__'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:439:in `all'
        from (irb):1
```

Model class Old/user.rb

```
class Old::User < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "old_database"

  # Because table name is lowercase
  def self.table_name() 
    "user"
  end
end
```

database.yml

```
old_database:
  adapter: mysql
  database: old_database
  username: root
  password: 
  socket: /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: can you post the full stack trace? run with -w flag

Comment: I'm having the same problem but witha new application seems like something bad happened when trying to install rails 3 using rvm because when i wen back to ruby 1.8 and ran my rails 2 app rake db:migrate is throwing this back `undefined method `more_results' for #<Mysql>`

Comment: Which version of the mysql gem are you using? I just did a test with a fresh app using rails 3.0.7 and mysql gem 2.8.1 and I can access a database exactly as you've described here.

Answer (score 0):

The latest MySQL gem (=>0.3.2) needs an additional gem to connect -- it's been architected just like the MSSQL-Server gem was in previous versions of Rails.

You also probably want to use the mysql2 (note the "2") gem